# Is PHP 5 Object Oriented?

Tags: php, php-5.3

I would like to know if PHP is Object Oriented, I read that from version 5 PHP now support features of OOP world. This means that PHP now became a full OO Language?

Do you have any feedback on developing using OO Style on PHP?

(Note: I do not have experience with PHP only C#).

Comment: I won't downvote, but a simple google search would have answered your question for you.

Comment: I believe that OOP level PHP now is pretty good. Only some hardcore JAVA (and similar language) purists might have objections. But thats just my 2cents.

Comment: PHP is a procedural language that has had OOP bolted onto the side. You can use as much or as little of the OOP functionality as you'd like.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers, I'm sorry to see your downvotes, unfortunately I was not able to get a full answer to my question on Google so I posted here on SO. Also My question ask about feedback on experience on PHP and OOP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP5 does support some OO features, but it is not "fully OO" in the way that some other languages are, like Ruby -- for instance, PHP5 still has a number of primitive types (string, number, and array) which are not presented as objects, and the vast majority of its standard library is presented as bare functions.

On the other hand, the same could be said of some other languages, like Java, which are commonly held up as great examples of OO. :)

Answer (score 8):

Languages cannot be "object oriented."  Only code can be.  PHP is a language that supports object orientation.  This does not automatically make code better by any means.

Answer (score 3):

PHP5 supports object oriented programming. However, it is not a "full" object oriented language like C#. Everything is not an object, and all the functions are still there. It's up to you to choose which style you would like to adopt.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call it object oriented myself, but it does have objects.

And it claims to be OO :P http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php